# Disappearing text field placeholders

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, applescript-objc

I'm having this issue where my text field placeholders are disappearing when I run the app.

The is what it looks like in the Interface Builder:
[image]

This is what you see when the app runs:
[image]

Edit: Just to clarify, this is an AppleScript project. Little to no Obj-C has been used.

Edit: Have feeling it has something to do with my empty strings in my properties.

```
property PONumber: ""
property PolicyCost: ""
property PolicyTerm: ""
```

I then have a binding between the variable and the text field.

Comment: What code do you have associated with this view?

Comment: @Fogmeister They update AppleScript variables.

Comment: You'll need to show some code in your question because your code is changing these textfields somewhere. Without any code we cannot debug this.

Comment: @Fogmeister Added edit.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are setting some values in your text fields at run time they are blank.

```
 textField.text = @"";
```

you can set placeholder

```
textField.placeholder = @"Your Placeholdertext";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
property PONumber: missing value
```

-- wire this property up to the NSTextField in interface builder.

...

```
PONumber's setStringValue:""
```

-- the field should then display the placeholder text

In ObjC terms, PONumber is a NSTextField*, and it displays an NSString*. It that string is empty, then the placeholder text you specified in IB (or in your code) is displayed.